# Creating relationship between tables of different aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a retail store data with 50000 records. One of the columns in that file is Segment (Home office, Corporate and Consumer). This data i have in one table. In another table i just have two columns - Segment, Forecast Sales. What query needs to be written to get the actual segment sales and Forecast Sales in single table or how should the relationship be created in SQL.

Data can be found here : https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd want toget for this sample.

Comment: You don't create relationships in SQL Server but you can define foreign keys to enforce consistency. Normally to solve this you pre-summarise the _retail store data_ table up to segment level. Then it's easy to combine. If you don't know how to write a query with `SUM` and `GROUP BY` then you'd better learn: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Data can be found here. https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236 . Imagine three rows representing each segment and corresponding forecasted Sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume table name [Orders] as per your excel and [Segment Forecast] for the table with columns [Segment], [Forecast Sales].

```
select sf.Segment,sum(o.sales) [Actual Sales],sf.[Forecast Sales]
from [Orders] o
inner join [Segment Forecast] sf on o.Segment=sf.Segment
group by sf.Segment,sf.[Forecast Sales]
```

Comment: This query will double count. If a given segment appears three times in [Orders], the forecast will be multiplied by three. Please test things before you accept them

Comment: Each [Orders] row will contribute its [Sales] value in the aggregation. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry I retract my comment - I'm so used to seeing this type of query with the forecasts summed.